# Why does this array change its value without being asked to?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array declared like this :

```
var gamme =
[
    ["A"],
    ["A♯","B♭"],
    ["B","C♭"],
    ["C","B♯"],
    ["C♯","D♭"],
    ["D"],
    ["D♯","E♭"],
    ["E","F♭"],
    ["F","E♯"],
    ["F♯","G♭"],
    ["G"],
    ["G♯","A♭"],
];
```

using this array, I’m generating another array.
I want temperamentEgal to look like this :
for example :

```
temperamentEgal[10] = [103.82617439498631, ["G♯","A♭"]]
temperamentEgal[25] = [233.08188075904502, ["A♯","B♭"]]
```

so this is what I do :

```
base = pow(2,1/12); // 2^(1/12)
for (i=0; i<12*octaves; i++) // octaves = 6
{
    temperamentEgal[i] = []
    temperamentEgal[i][0] = 55*pow(base,i); // = 138.6
    temperamentEgal[i][1] = gamme[i%12]; // = ["C♯","D♭"]
    console.log("gamme["+i%12+"] = " + gamme[i%12]);
    for (j=0; j<temperamentEgal[i][1].length; j++)
    {
        var octaveNote = 1+i/12;
        octaveNote = floor(octaveNote);
        temperamentEgal[i][1][j] +=  str(octaveNote);
    }
}
```

As you can see, at no point I’m changing the value of `gamme`
nonetheless, as the loop progresses, I’m getting this from the console.log :

```
gamme[0] = A
gamme[1] = A♯,B♭
gamme[2] = B,C♭
gamme[3] = C,B♯
gamme[4] = C♯,D♭
gamme[5] = D
gamme[6] = D♯,E♭
gamme[7] = E,F♭
gamme[8] = F,E♯
gamme[9] = F♯,G♭
gamme[10] = G
gamme[11] = G♯,A♭
gamme[0] = A1
gamme[1] = A♯1,B♭1
gamme[2] = B1,C♭1
gamme[3] = C1,B♯1
gamme[4] = C♯1,D♭1
gamme[5] = D1
gamme[6] = D♯1,E♭1
gamme[7] = E1,F♭1
gamme[8] = F1,E♯1
gamme[9] = F♯1,G♭1
gamme[10] = G1
gamme[11] = G♯1,A♭1
```

If I comment out `temperamentEgal[i][1][j] +=  str(octaveNote);` it’s not happening anymore.

Why would changing the value of `temperamentEgal[i][1]` change the value of `gamme[i%12]` as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while you don't change `gamme`, you change the anonymous arrays referenced on this line:

```
temperamentEgal[i][1] = gamme[i%12];
```

both right side and left side of this assignment now point to the same Array objects - if you want to modify a copy of the Array, you should copy the values of the Array, not the reference to the Array object:

ES5: `temperamentEgal[i][1] = gamme[i%12].slice();`

ES6: `temperamentEgal[i][1] = [...gamme[i%12]]` using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Copy_an_array)